# Are databases more expensive to host and serve than files?

Tags: database, disk-space, web-hosting

I've observed a large percentage of hosts have very harsh limits on database space but generous limits on disk space.

100GB disk / 2 GB database seems quite common.

To me, this makes little sense for the end user. I tend to think that most user-generated content would end up in the database, and I know a number of even popular forum systems tend to plug their images into the DB in binary format.

It's clear that hosts are in the business for earning a profit, thus any decisions they make will be based primarily on income. From this, it's a simple jump to conclude that it's likely that databases cost more to run. What about databases, or their use, causes them to be more expensive to run?

Comment: You get what you pay for.  Quality hosts don't do this.

Comment: I'm not trying to obtain a cheap host. I'm just curious as to whether there's a technical reason that database storage offered is often lower than disk space - I don't feel that justifies a down-vote. If you think so, please explain.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as "Primarily opinion-based", so I won't offer a speculation here. But you can ask this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access); almost any technical topic is on-topic for discussion in chat.

Comment: The technical reason is they can put more people on a single server if they do this.  This is not on topic here at Superuser and the quality of the post is not high enough to flag for migration to another website.  The low quality nature of this particular question is the reason for the downvote

Comment: "The technical reason is they can put more people on a single server if they do this." Why would that make a difference? Surely the database could be hosted on the same server as their actual website is, in which case cutting the space for the database would be justified. I'm not asking why there's a low allowance for databases, I'm asking where there's a significantly higher allowance for regular files. I was expecting an answer along the lines of "Databases take more power to run as ____ thus hosts want to keep them small". I don't feel that your response can explain this.

Comment: Unless your DB consists of a tiny number of enormous files, DBs tend to consume more CPU cycles per gigabyte of content because the content is always being searched, indexed, parsed, updated, etc., and most DBs consist of a huge number of small objects, which causes the DB server to get "metadata'ed to death". Basically, 20 GB of stuff in a database will almost always represent a much greater CPU and I/O throughput workload for the server than 20 GB of stuff that's just on the filesystem and being served over HTTP. The DB has to *process* the stuff; HTTP just copies it around.

Comment: Of course you can contrive a database workload that treats a database as if it were a filesystem, and store four 5GB movies as BLOBs in a database, and that wouldn't take up much metadata at all; but hosting providers realize that most workloads are nothing like that, and if they let customers use 100 GB of database space, that would likely consist of tens of millions or billions of records, hundreds of tables, gigantic indexes of long text fields, and other such CPU-intensive content. Throw in a few slow SQL queries and the DB's brought to its knees.

Comment: For reference, there was a meta post on SE some time in 2013 (so, after SO/SU/SF have been well-established sites for several years) where one of the SE devs mentioned that the entire database for all of StackExchange took up something like 10 GB. So 20 GB in a database under a typical workload is **enormous**, especially if strings are compressed and/or de-duplicated (they are in many DB implementations).

Comment: Thanks :) Any chance you could drop that as an answer? I thought it'd have something to do with CPU usage - Sorry if I worded my question badly, but I was hoping for a justified technical response about the proportions like you gave, rather than a justification for low numbers (Which I think is what my question was misinterpreted as asking)

Comment: Not going to drop it as an answer, because I fully expect the question will be closed. It's a poor fit for the site, but since you didn't drop by chat, I figured I'd at least give a satisfying "answer". If I post an *actual answer* though, I'll just end up losing any rep you give me when the question's deleted, most likely. Not indicating I agree/disagree with the policy, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for informing me either way, I guess. I still don't understand why it isn't an appropriate fit, though. I may well have worded it in an opinion way, but the question I'm asking comes down to wondering the factual reason for why file space is cheaper to serve. I don't think that is an opinionated topic at all, no more than any questions asked here.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a superuser-appropriate question.

Comment: Well, the question now has 1 upvote and 2 downvotes and I haven't voted on it either way. It also has 2 close votes. I don't think it'll last, regardless. :/

Comment: What they are trying to say is: phrase your question(s) differently (make it more technical in nature as to a 'why is it this way' and less 'opion' based). Based on your comments and concerns you're question is valid enough to be on this site, though not phrased in the best (hence it might get closed due to it's potential to be 'off-topic' as it's too 'opion' based).

Comment: Thanks txtechhelp, I've tried to improve it a bit, but I'm still struggling to word it well. Is it better like this?

Comment: I think you're going to see it get closed anyway (whether the closing is justified or not, actually!) just because the question starts with "why". "Why" triggers a kneejerk reaction in many people to close the question because they perceive a "Why" question as being so open-ended that it invites people to answer by registering an opinion (which may or may not be substantiated), any of which are equally valid as the next, as long as they're not contradictory or representing false statements as facts. That kind of question ends up leading to *enormous* amounts of discussion.

Comment: It only takes 5 VTCs for it to be closed. The chances of 3 more coming are quite high. However, I'm going to bring this up in Root Access chat with a moderator to get his take on it.

Comment: Fair enough, again thanks though, for being impartial and discussing the issue.

Comment: Looks like it's [moderator's night out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15036516#15036516) :P Will have to wait a bit maybe to get a mod to weigh in. My personal opinion as a 10k+ user is it's a marginal question, I'm on the fence about it. Some good answers down below though. We'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harddisks are cheap. Even if an ISP promises some hundred GB to every single user, most of them will not use that space to the limit as transfering 100 GB to a server might take some time.

The bottom line is:
You are descibing an entry level system. Most users using this kind of system have no clue of database management. Many never heard of indexing / database normalization / ... Most likely they will burn cpu-cycles with redundant searches or expensive joins. In addition a responsive database needs a lot of RAM for the queries themselfes, the query cache (...). At this point it gets expensive for the ISP.

Besides 2 GB for a database is plenty for beginners. If you need more you might want to switch to a dedicated database server and SSDs.

Answer (score 3):

Most larger hosts cluster servers for use with different needs - primarily that the MySQL servers would be on separate systems to the web server systems. The reason for why hosts limit the MySQL disk space is because it's best practice to store them with SSD's over HDD's - as we all know, SSD's cost a hell of a lot more per GB than HDD's, which explains why they limit the space as they do.

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is Backups and Transaction Log files. DB backups, even on small databases become quite large over time, requiring a [backup cycling strategy](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/grandfather-father-son). Transaction log files on high usage databases, even if they store only a small amount of data can become monstrous, and fill your drive with little or no warning. I've had a number of critical services stop because I too my eye off log file size, and filled the media. then you just get errors.